# Extract YouTube Thumbnails From Videos Within A Playlist & Display On Webpage

Tags: html, css, youtube-api, alignment, thumbnails

My webpage plays a YouTube playlist and displays the track name at the bottom (spent most of the day on that), I figured it would be great to have a thumbnail of the specific video playing from the playlist displayed at the bottom next to the track title. I understand how to do this for a specific video, but how would I implement this for a playlist of videos? It is important that the image is refreshed for each new song that is played.

Here is a jsfiddle with my current work: https://jsfiddle.net/ruumL5s7/

ALSO, I am having issues with vertically aligning the video and chat divs between the top and bottom bar. I'm also running into issues with the bottom bar not staying a 'full' bar when the screen is resized (the different divs all break apart), I've tried a couple ideas to prevent that, with no avail. So any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <title>Chat</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
              </head>

            <div class="all-content">

              <body>

                <div class="header-bar">
                  <div class="bar">

                      <img src="C:\Users\jlewa\Desktop\assets\affinity_fm_only_letters.png" class="top-logo" style="float: left;">

                      <ul class="standard-nav" style="float: left;">

                      <li>Home</li>
                      <li>Lyrics Hub</li>
                      <li>Affinity LIVE</li>
                      <li>Merchandise</li>

                      </ul>

                  </div>
                  <div class="dropshadow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="container-middle-third">
                  <div class="youtube-video" style="float: left;">
                    <div class="DJ-text">Affinity FM DJ Room</div>
                    <div class="DJ-underline"></div>
                    <div id="player" style="width: 1280px; height: 720px;"></div></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="chat" style="float: left;">
                    <div class="Chat-text">Chat</div>
                    <div class="Chat-underline"></div>
                    <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Chat">
                    <div class="info-rect">Info</div>
                    <div class="chat-messages"></div>
                    <textarea placeholder="Join the conversation..."></textarea>
                    <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
                  </div>

                <div class="bottom-bar">

                  <div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" style="float: left"></div>

                  <div class="title-bar" style="float: left;">

                    <div class="title" id="title"></div>
                    <div class="dj-playing">Affinity FM is playing</div>

                    <div class="progress-background">
                      <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="subscribe" style="float: left;">

                    <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="SAMusicPlaylist" data-layout="full" data-theme="dark" data-count="default"></div> 

                  </div>

                </div>

                <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

                <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

                <script>
                  (function() {
                    var getNode = function(s) {
                      return document.querySelector(s);
                    },

                        // Get required nodes
                        status = getNode('.chat-status span'),
                        messages = getNode('.chat-messages'), 
                        textarea = getNode('.chat textarea'),
                        chatName = getNode('.chat-name'),

                        statusDefault = status.textContent,    

                        setStatus = function(s){
                          status.textContent = s;

                          if(s !== statusDefault){
                            var delay = setTimeout(function(){
                              setStatus(statusDefault);
                              clearInterval(delay);
                            }, 3000);
                          }
                        };

                    //try connection
                    try{
                      var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
                    } catch(e){
                      //Set status to warn user
                    }

                    if(socket !== undefined){

                      //Listen for output
                      socket.on('output', function(data){
                        if(data.length){
                          //Loop through results
                          for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1){
                            var message = document.createElement('div');
                            message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                            message.textContent = ': ' + data[x].message;
                            var name=document.createElement('span');
                            name.setAttribute('class', 'userName');
                            name.textContent = data[x].name;

                            message.insertBefore(name, message.firstChild);

                            //Append
                            messages.appendChild(message);
                            messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                          }
                        }
                      });

                      //Listen for a status
                      socket.on('status', function(data){
                        setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);

                        if(data.clear === true){
                          textarea.value = '';
                        }
                      });

                      //Listen for keydown
                      textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                        var self = this,
                            name = chatName.value;

                        if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false){
                          socket.emit('input', {
                            name: name,
                            message: self.value
                          });
                        }
                      });
                    }

                  })();
                </script>
                <script>
                  var time_total;
                  var timeout_setter;
                  var player;
                  var tag = document.createElement("script");//This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously

                  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                  //This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) OR uses the iframe if it exists at the "player" element after the API code downloads
                  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
                  {
                    player = new YT.Player("player",
                                           {
                      height: "853",
                      width: "480",
                      /* videoId: "GGmxVDXM5X2UxaP9PvWQ4Z171DXyGcq", */
                      playerVars: {
                        listType:'playlist',
                        list: 'PL_GGmxVDXM5X2UxaP9PvWQ4Z171DXyGcq',
                        controls: '0',
                        html5: '1',
                        cc_load_policy: '0',
                        disablekb: '1',
                        iv_load_policy: '3',
                        modestbranding: '1',
                        showinfo: '0',
                        rel: '0',


                      },
                      events:
                      {
                        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
                        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
                      }

                    });
                  }


                var num = (1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));


                  //The API will call this function when the video player is ready
                  function onPlayerReady(event)
                  {
                    event.target.playVideo();
                    time_total  = convert_to_mins_and_secs(player.getDuration(), 1);
                    loopy();


                    player.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'onPlayerStateChange');


                    player.setShuffle( {
                    'shufflePlaylist': 1
                    } );    
                  }

                  function loopy()
                  {
                    var current_time = convert_to_mins_and_secs(player.getCurrentTime(), 0);
                    document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width = (player.getCurrentTime()/player.getDuration())*100+"%";
                    console.log( current_time + " / " + time_total);
                    timeout_setter = setTimeout(loopy, 300);
                  }

                  function convert_to_mins_and_secs(seconds, minus1)
                  {
                    var mins    = (seconds>=60) ?Math.round(seconds/60):0;
                    var secs    = (seconds%60!=0) ?Math.round(seconds%60):0;
                    var secs    = (minus1==true) ?(secs-1):secs; //Youtube always displays 1 sec less than its duration time!!! Then we have to set minus1 flag to true for converting player.getDuration()
                    var time    = mins + ":" + ((secs<10)?"0"+secs:secs);
                    return time;
                  }

                  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes
                  function onPlayerStateChange(event)
                  {
                    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED)
                    {
                      console.log("END!");
                      clearTimeout(timeout_setter);
                      document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.cssText = "transition: none;";


                    }
                    else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)
                    {
                      console.log("PLAYING");
                      loopy();
                      document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.cssText = "transition: all 300ms linear 0s;";
                      console.log(player.getPlayerState());
                      if (player.getPlayerState() == 1) {
                      document.getElementById( "title" ).innerText = player.getVideoData().title;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED)
                    {
                        event.target.playVideo();
                        console.log("PLAUSED");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      console.log(event.data);
                    }
                  }
                </script>

              </body>
            </div>
           </html>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
          background-color: #0f0f17;
          margin: 0px;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .container-middle-third{
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-left: 70px;
        }

        body,
        textarea,
        input {
          font: 13px "Raleway", sans-serif;
          color: #ffffff;

        }

        .all-content{
            width: 1920px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .bar{
          height: 90px;
          width: 1920px;
          background-color: #15151d;   
        }

        .top-logo{
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin-left: 4%
        }

        /*li{
            display: inline;
            padding-right: 20px;
        }

        .standard-nav {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            line-height: 13px;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-left: 63%;
            max-height: 100%;
        } */

        .DJ-text{
          font-weight: 700;
          /*position:relative;*/
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .Chat-text{
          font-weight: 700;
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .DJ-underline{
          width: 1280px;
          height: 1px;
          position:relative;top:10px;
          background-color: #3f3f45;
          margin: 0px 0px 40px;
        }

        .Chat-underline{
          width: 100%;
          position:relative;
          /*left:-140px;*/
          float:right;
          height: 1px;
          position:relative;top:10px;
          background-color: #3f3f45;
          margin: 0px 0px 40px;
        }

        .youtube-video{
        position: relative;
        }
        .transparent-layer{
          width: 850px;
          height: 477px;
          pointer-events: none;
          background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        .ad{
          width: 728px;
          height: 90px;
          border: 1px solid #000000;
          margin-left: 11px;
          margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .chat {
          position: relative;
          min-width: 400px;
          margin: 0px 0px 0px 112px;
        }
        .chat-messages,
        .chat-textarea,
        .chat-name {
          border: 1px solid #1a1a23;
          background-color: #1a1a23;
        }

        .userName{
          font-weight: 700;
          color: #079ce0;
        }

        .chat-messages {
          width:380px;
          height:586px;
          overflow-y:scroll;
          padding:10px;
        }

        .chat-message {
          margin-bottom:10px;
        }

        .info-rect{
          height: 40px;
          width: 180px;
          padding:10px;
          max-width: 100%;
          margin:0;
          border:0;
          display: flex; 
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;  
          font-weight: 700;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          background-color: #15151d
        }

        .chat-name{
          height: 40px;
          max-width: 100%;
          width: 180px;
          padding:10px;
          border:0;
          margin:0;
          font-weight: 700;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          float:left;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .chat textarea {
          width:380px;
          padding:10px;
          margin:0;
          border-top:0;
          max-width:100%;
          border-top: 1px solid #0f0f17;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a23;
          border-right: 1px solid #1a1a23;
          border-left: 1px solid #1a1a23;
          background-color: #1a1a23;

        }

        .chat-status {
          color: #bbb;
          opacity: 0;
          background-color: #0f0f17;
        }

        .info-rect,
        .chat textarea,
        .chat-name { 
          max-width: 100%; 
        }


        .bottom-bar{
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;  
            display:table;

        }

        .thumbnail{
          width: 90px;
          height: 80px;
          opacity: 0.2;
          background-color: #ffffff;
        }   

        .title-bar{
          width:1372px;
          height: 80px;
          background-color: #1a1a23;
        }
        .title{
          font-weight: 700;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          margin-left: 30px;
          margin-top: 25px;
        }
        .dj-playing{
          margin-left: 30px;
        }
        .progress-background{
          width: 1372px;
          height: 3px;
          background-color: #313139;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0;
        }
        .progress-bar{
          height: 3px;
          width: 0px;
          transition: all 300ms linear;
          background-color: #fa1d57;
          bottom: 0;
        }
        .subscribe{
          width: 458px;
          height: 80px;
          background-color: #15151d;
            display:table-cell;
        }
        .g-ytsubscribe{
            width: 450px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
```

Comment: http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-thumbnail-image/

Answer (score 0):

This time you have to use a **key** with the Youtube API 3.

You can do that with either js or Php.

**Php**

```
<?
    $api_key        = "AIzaSyDRfgPj9a2vnckVkSGoKktNfrozbMvjkdw";
    $play_list_id   = "PLcV3JzAz3r32-on4upkyAv0VtvYXAl-Nz";
    $url            = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id=" . $play_list_id;

    $ch         = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $response_raw = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response_raw);

    echo "default image :" . $response->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->default->url;
    echo "<br />\n<br />\n";
    echo "medium image :" . $response->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->medium->url;
    echo "<br />\n<br />\n";
    echo "maxres image :" . $response->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->maxres->url;
    echo "<br />\n<br />\n";
    echo print_r($response, 1);
?>
```

The most important thing in the script is the **url** with the query parameters. Just remember to replace the **$api_key**, and the **$play_list_id** with your own.

Now with javascript, it's almost the same thing.

**JS**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function make_request()
{
    var response        = "";
    var response1       = "";
    var api_key         = "AIzaSyBaS4_vwohJW7Ndb9EkjSqsoD75O4f4jXI";
    var play_list_id    = "PLcV3JzAz3r32-on4upkyAv0VtvYXAl-Nz";
    var url             = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id=" + play_list_id + "&key=" + api_key;

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "get",
        async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            response = JSON.stringify(data);
            response1 = data;
        }
    });
    alert(response1.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url);
    console.log(response1.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url);
    console.log(response);
}

function init()
{
    gapi.client.setApiKey("AIzaSyBaS4_vwohJW7Ndb9EkjSqsoD75O4f4jXI");
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3').then(make_request);
}
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

Take a look at those in action :

- http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_21/curl_any.php
- http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_21/curl_any.zip
- http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_21/gapi_1.html

But remember: when you do it with Php, you have to create a Google server key. When you do it with js, guess what? You do it with a browser key. But most important, remember to enable Youtube data api 3 in developers console!

Reference to get a KEY :
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#choose-google-services

Comment: ok yes, this was where I got caught up. So I have the ability to use both api v2 and v3 in the same code? I'm not sure why, but I figured that this would cause a problem

Comment: You have to understand that we are referring to 2 different api the `YouTube Player API` and the `YouTube Data API` 

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: oh I see, working through your javascript code now. If I understand correctly, I need to place a line of code beneath 'console.log(response);' like this 'document.getElementById( "thumbnail" );' in order to extract the thumbnail for use inside my thumbnail div? I'm actively going through API basics, but it's like trying to drink water from a fire hose haha

Comment: No. The `response` variable has all your data in a big object. All you need is to understand it and extract what you need from there.

Comment: ok, guess I just don't fundamentally understand what's going on yet. I'll study this snippet and get back to you if I hit a roadblock

Comment: Look at that : http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_21/gapi_3.html the console.log is just there to show you the big object. The way you extract an image is right inside that alert line = 27

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115224/discussion-between-georges-user2251342-and-jordan-lewallen).